# c# windows forms Modify web browser control to look like facebook mobile

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, mobile

I am trying to get Facebook access token from desktop application, the problem is that, redirect the login page to a web browser control on a from, is there any way to make the web browser looks like mobile login, meaning that the login page resize arrange its items depending on the form's size such as mobile.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I the parameter display=popup with the end point "https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth".